# How to give root power to another user

Tags: root, accounts

How to Give all the powers Of Root account to another user account? With full command and detail.

Answer (score 9):

It's best to first look in /etc/sudoers for lines that look like:

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

It's the "wheel" group on CentOS and "admin" on Ubuntu.  If you are OK with giving this user all root powers, just make them a member of the group:

```
usermod -a -G wheel username
```

Or if you want to be more restrictive, add a line to give them more specific permissions:

```
username   ALL = (named) /usr/sbin/named
```

This lets username run /usr/sbin/named, but only as user named.  In some distros, you can add this line to a new file /etc/sudoers.d/username so that your distro can upgrade the delivered base file without stomping on your edits.

Then, your user can run

```
sudo -u named /usr/sbin/named
```

in the more restrictive case, or in the former example

```
sudo make me-a-sandwich
```

to run a command as root.  If you just want a shell as root,

```
sudo -s
```

Comment: On Ubuntu, it suffices to add the user to the `sudo` group.

Comment: @reinierpost However, this is RHEL, not ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the tag.

Answer (score 6):

[Sudo](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s3-wstation-privileges-limitroot-sudo.html) should provide you with the most common way to do this.
Any member of the [wheel group](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/2/html/Getting_Started_Guide/ch02s03.html) will have sudo rights by default.

Putting it together you will want to add any user you want to have root privileges to the wheel group. They will then preface any command with `sudo` to run a command (and only that command) as root. At the end of the command they will be back to a regular user.

Compare:

```
ls /root
```

and

```
sudo ls /root
```

Comment: Perhaps just add that to enable `sudo` for a user the user should be added to the `sudo` group

Comment: It depends on which variety of Unix you're running. It varies between Linux distributions, for instance: Ubuntu has the `sudo` group, CentOS hasn't.

Comment: OP tagged this Red Hat.

Answer (score -1):

If what you want is to mimic root but with another name, just create a new user and modify /etc/passwd. Set the 3rd and 4th fields to 0 and you will have another root user.

In the end being root is just having UID=0 which is what you did in the previous step.

Comment: True, but probably a bad idea.

Comment: Depends on what you want. It is your responsability.